# angular link function iElement magic in angular-ui example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Angular provides the instance element of the current scope within a link function.

The *iElement* angular passes is capable of doing things beyond a standard HTML element. How does angular do this? Wrap it with jQuery first?

How does the link element in this [angular-ui tinymce implementation](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/tinymce/tinymce.js) get the tinymce method  e.g. the method shown below on line 49:

```
elm.tinymce();
```

I get that the ui-tinymce attribute links to the directive named uiTinymce, and that tinymce is included in the main html, but i don't understand how elm get the method tinymce.

As a reference I've provided the relevant documentation on iElement from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive below.

> **Linking function:**

```
function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
```

> The link function is responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM. > It is executed after the template has been cloned. This is where most of the directive logic > will be put.
>
> **scope** - Scope - The scope to be used by the directive for registering watches.
>
> **iElement** - instance element - The element where the directive is to be used. It is safe to  manipulate the children of the element only in postLink function since the children have already been linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`angular.element`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) page:

> Note: All element references in Angular are always wrapped with jQuery
>   or jqLite; they are never raw DOM references.

So yes, the `iElement` argument is a jQueryLite, or full jQuery object, which has all of the relevant additional methods that jQuery/jQueryLite provide.

This includes any additional methods that are added via jQuery's plugin mechanisms, which have the effect of being able to call those methods directly on the jQuery object itself.

So the TinyMCE JS file would have code to add in a `.tinymce()` function to all jQuery objects, which is how the `iElement` object has it.

Does that make sense?

Comment: This makes sense. Looking at the source for the angular-ui main site, I see they are loading jquery.tinymce.js which falls in line with what you said. To make sure I'm getting it I mocked up a similar example which integrates the aloha.js WYSIWYG editor. http://plnkr.co/edit/TjpTGt. It looks like Aloha wraps itself in jQuery as well (so is it double wrapped when passed as an element?) What is the difference between using `Aloha.bind('some-event' function(){});` in the link function of a directive and `elm.aloha.bind('some-event' function(){});`?

Comment: So from the looks of things on the Aloha site, and the source code, this is a case of using event delegation to restrict the scope of events handled. If you know how events bubble up the tree in JS, then you will know that you can either bind a single event handler to a top level node, like the `<body>` tag (which is what `Aloha.bind()` does behind the scenes), or you can bind it directly to the element itself. Or, you can bind it to an element that is above the event source, but much closer to it than the `<body>` tag, which is what I think `elm.aloha.bind(...)` does. Make any sense?

Comment: Great, I think I understand. I put a console.log('event fired') inside both of the event callbacks listed above. The Aloha.bind() event fires but when replaced with the elm.aloha.bind() event binding the event does not fire (or at least the console.log('event fired') does not print). Anyway, I appreciate the answers above. Would it be courteous for me to start a bounty and award it to you?

Comment: @Funkyeah I don't believe a bounty is appropriate, much as I am addicted to rep points on here, but I appreciate your marking my answer as correct and upvoting it.